# I would like to use an input field with values coming from a different place

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, use-effect, react-forms

I'm trying to display a fixture football games and enable the user to predict the scores. There are two arrays, one is the called FIXTURES, the other is called SAVED_PREDICTIONS and shows what the user has saved to firestore.

In order to save PREDICTIONS to firestore I have to create objects from arrays, so instead of this

FIXTURES ARRAY:

```
0: {id: 416384, score: {…}, etc..}
```

I'm saving like this:

SAVED_PREDICTIONS ARRAY:

```
0:
416375: {id: 416375, score: {…}, etc..}
```

I have two components, Predict and PredictField. PredictField prints out the inputs for each fixture. I'm trying to use the values from the SAVED_PREDICTIONS inside these fields however because this array uses the matchId as a key I can't seem to reference it correctly.

Can someone help me to reference the correct SAVED_PREDICTIONS ARRAY object for each FIXTURE input, using the matchId?

predict component:

```
{fixture.map((el: any, i: number) => (
                                            <PredictField
                                                key={i}
                                                allFixtures={data}
                                                fixture={el}
                                                predictions={predictions}
                                                matchDay={el.matchday}
                                                index={index}
                                                innerIndex={i}
                                                onchange={onchange}
                                            />
                                        ))}
```

PredictField component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export const PredictField = (props: any) => {
    const { fixture, onchange, index, allFixtures, innerIndex } = props;
    const predictions = useSelector((state: any) => state.predictForm);
    const [home, setHome] = useState(0);
    const [away, setAway] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (predictions.userPredictions[0]) {
            let test = Object.keys(predictions.userPredictions[0][index]);
            setHome(
                predictions.userPredictions[0][index][test[innerIndex]].score.fullTime.homeTeam === null
                    ? 0
                    : predictions.userPredictions[0][index][test[innerIndex]].score.fullTime.homeTeam
            );
            setAway(
                predictions.userPredictions[0][index][test[innerIndex]].score.fullTime.awayTeam === null
                    ? 0
                    : predictions.userPredictions[0][index][test[innerIndex]].score.fullTime.awayTeam
            );
        }
    }, []);

    const handleOnChangeHome = (e: any) => {
        setHome(e.value);
        onchange(e);
    };
    const handleOnChangeAway = (e: any) => {
        setAway(e.value);
        onchange(e);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                {fixture.matchday}, {fixture.id}
            </p>
            <label>{fixture.homeTeam.name.replace("FC", "")}</label>
            <input
                name={`homeTeam-${fixture.id}`}
                type="number"
                value={home}
                onChange={(e) => handleOnChangeHome(e.target)}
            />
            <input
                name={`awayTeam-${fixture.id}`}
                type="number"
                value={away}
                onChange={(e) => handleOnChangeAway(e.target)}
            />
            <label>{fixture.awayTeam.name.replace("FC", "")}</label>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Example of FIXTURE and SAVED_PREDICTIONS object inside the arrays (they have the same keys only referenced differently in the SAVED_PREDICTIONS using matchId as a key):

```
  {
    "score": {
        "extraTime": {
            "awayTeam": null,
            "homeTeam": null
        },
        "fullTime": {
            "awayTeam": 0,
            "homeTeam": 2
        },
        "halfTime": {
            "awayTeam": null,
            "homeTeam": null
        },
        "penalties": {
            "awayTeam": null,
            "homeTeam": null
        },
        "winner": "Crystal Palace FC",
        "duration": "REGULAR"
    },
    "matchday": 1,
    "id": 416384,
    "awayTeam": {
        "id": 57,
        "name": "Arsenal FC"
    },
    "referees": [],
    "odds": {
        "msg": "Activate Odds-Package in User-Panel to retrieve odds."
    },
    "lastUpdated": "2022-06-16T15:49:58Z",
    "season": {
        "currentMatchday": 1,
        "id": 1490,
        "startDate": "2022-08-05",
        "endDate": "2023-05-28"
    },
    "homeTeam": {
        "name": "Crystal Palace FC",
        "id": 354
    },
    "group": null,
    "utcDate": "2022-08-05T19:00:00Z",
    "status": "SCHEDULED",
    "stage": "REGULAR_SEASON"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used .find because it returns the array of objects that matches the expression. Then with that 'found' array object I use the 'fixture.id' to reference the exact object

```
let found = predictions.userPredictions[0].find((el: any) => {
                                    return el[fixture.id];
                                });
                    
        setHome(found[fixture.id].score.fullTime.homeTeam === null ? 0 : found[fixture.id].score.fullTime.homeTeam);
                
        setAway(found[fixture.id].score.fullTime.awayTeam === null ? 0 : found[fixture.id].score.fullTime.awayTeam);
```